# Android rounded corners on layout are not showing if child elements are receded with margin

Tags: android

I have a constraint layout to which I applied `background="@drawable/rounded_corners"` where rounded corners looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

all the child elements of this layout have a margin of 10dp left and right . This is, in turn, not making the rounded edges appear. When I remove the edges, the rounded corners appear.

What is the proper solution for this? if there is no proper solution what are some workarounds/hacks to make this happen?

Comment: have you tried adding a 10dp padding to the parent layout ?

Comment: Maybe with a CardView? I am using CardViews with rounded corners in my app with RelativeLayout inside, and the views inside that RelativeLayout have margins, and is working ok. I don't know if it would work with ConstraintLayout, but as far as I know it should.

Comment: also i  suggest having a slightly larger padding... say 15dp and use it like the first comment states